# Reverse for 'profileEditor' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['regisApp/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/profileEditor/\\Z']

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

Hello  every one like a lot of people I'm having this ( Reverse for 'profileEditor' with no arguments not found.  1 pattern(s) tried: ['regisApp/(?P[0-9]+)/profileEditor/\Z'] ) I've been trying some of the solution given to other people but with no luck.

This is what I'm trying to pass in my home.html menu, is a page were the user can edit their profile

```
<li><a href="{% url 'profileEditor' %}">Edit Profile</a></li>
```

in my url.py I have this path

```
path('<int:pk>/profile_Editor/', editProfilePage.as_view(), name="profileEditor"),
```

And this is my views.py class

```
class editProfilePage(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = "registration/profileEditor.html"
    fields = [
        'bio', 'profile_pic', 'website_url', 'facebook_url', 'instagram_url', 'github_url'
    ]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

I don't get it cuz I did the same process for some of the other pages and they are working fine

Comment: You need to pass the value for the primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the info man it worked I just added ```pk=user.pk``` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For those that don't get it yet what I did to fix my code was t add a `pk=user.id` after `'profileEditor'` so it looks like this now

```
<li><a href="{% url 'profileEditor' pk=user.id %}">Edit Profile</a></li>
```

also you can do it this way

```
<li><a href="{% url 'profileEditor' user.profile.id %}">Edit Profile</a></li>
```

Thanks to @Willem Van Onsem